# Compare Boolean variables within Time Window of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like so:

```
   datetime         Online   TEST
61 2018-03-03       True   False
62 2018-03-04       True   False
63 2018-03-05       True   False
64 2018-03-06       True   False
65 2018-03-07       True   False
66 2018-03-08       True   False
67 2018-03-09       True   False
68 2018-03-10       True   False
69 2018-03-11       False  False
70 2018-03-12       False  False
```

I need to check that for each `False` in the `TEST` column, that within a date range of 7 days that there is a `False` in the `Online` column. For example, on 2018-03-03, since `TEST` is False, I would want to check all plus or minus 7 days (ie plus or minus `timedelta(days = 7)`) for False values in the `Online` column. So since there are no False `Online` values within a 7 day time frame, then we would return a False. On the other hand, consider the date 2018-03-09, where `Online` is True and `TEST` is False. Since there is a False in `Online` on the day 2018-03-11, I need to return a boolean True value saying that there was a False within my 7 day time range.

I can achieve this using some slow and ugly looping mechanisms (ie go through each row using `DataFrame.iterrows()`, check if `TEST` is false, then pull the time window of plus or minus 7 days to see if `Online` also has a corresponding `False` value. But I would ideally like to have something snazzier and faster. For a visual, this is what I need my final dataframe to look like:

```
   datetime         Online   TEST   Check
61 2018-03-03       True   False    False
62 2018-03-04       True   False    True
63 2018-03-05       True   False    True
64 2018-03-06       True   False    True
65 2018-03-07       True   False    True
66 2018-03-08       True   False    True
67 2018-03-09       True   False    True
68 2018-03-10       True   False    True
69 2018-03-11       False  False    True
70 2018-03-12       False  False    True
```

Any ideas out there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is datetime field always in sorted order?

Comment: In my case yes, I sorted it before creating the current dataframe.

Comment: Is it expected that all dates are present?  Do you want +/- 7 rows or do you want +/- 7 days?  If all days are present then those are the same.  Just asking for clarification.

Comment: All dates are present in the full dataframe, so technically yes +/- 7 days is equivalent to +/- 7 rows in my specific case.

Comment: See if this does what you want `df.Online.rolling(15, center=True, min_periods=1).apply(np.nanmin).eq(0)`

Comment: Not quite, I should never recieve a True value if `Online` and `TEST` are both True. The output should be True if and only if `TEST` is False, and there is a False value for `Online` within a +/- 7 day window. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon great @piRSquared comments (I didn't even know about the `rolling` method, it seems very useful!), you can use

```
check = ~(df.TEST + df.Online.rolling(15, center=True, min_periods=1).apply(np.prod).eq(1))
```

The second summand creates a Series object in which every element is a boolean indicating if there is not any `False` value in a window of size 15; this is achieved by multiplying (NumPy's `prod` function) all the values inside this rolling window.

The sum (with the logical inverse operator `~`) is what compares booleans so we only get `True` in the `Check` series if there are two `False` in both columns (element-wise, of course).

Hope it helps.